# How to grep only json files(exclude.json.gz)?

Tags: linux, grep

I tried this

```
 grep -r --include=\*.json 'ticr_calculated_3' ./
```

Got nothing,although I have files

```
tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-52-59.json
tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-55-08.json
tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-57-30.json
tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-59-59.json
```

Why?

Comment: do the files themselves contain the string `ticr_calculated_3`? `grep` searches contents of file not filenames

Comment: `grep` looks for data inside files. You seem to want to look for file with a certain string in their _names_, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search the contents of `.json` files but not `.json.gz` files:

```
$ grep 'pattern' *.json
```